# NIntegrate not evaluating. "Interpolating Function"

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation

I am trying to numerically evaluate an integral. I have a function to be integrated, `ftbI[s,a]` with undetermined variable(s) `a`. I create a function that evaluates the integral, given the value of this variable, i.e. :

`FI[a]:=Nintegrate[ftbI[s,a],{s,slower,supper}]`

Now, inside of `ftbI` are other functions. One of these functions is an interpolation between some data points. The integral will integrate up to `Inf` , so extrapolation will be used, but this is okay.

If I try to evaluate `FI[a]`, the integral gets stuck and doesn't seem to progress. So I try to evaluate just the function `ftbI[s,a]` at some point, and I get the attached result. [image: Evaluating ftbI]

You'll see that there are a bunch of these "interpolatingFunctions" floating around. I am assuming that this is the problem with my Nintegrate. So my question is, what are these interpolatingfunctions? I've tried evaluating the part of `ftbI` that is the interpolation part that I mentioned above, and it seems to give me a real number anywhere within the region of integration, so I am unclear why my `ftbI` can't be evaluated properly.

Any guesses as to what is going on here, or things I can try to further explore issue are greatly appreciated. I might be wrong as to the issue of my integration, what I have said is just my guess. Thank you

Comment: A numeric integration requires all variables to have numeric values, e.g., `FI[a_?NumericQ] := Nintegrate[ftbI[s, a], {s, slower, supper}]` However, the cause of your problems cannot be determined without the appropriate definitions/code.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem (as seen in the image of the output) is that you are passing a complex number as an argument to an `InterpolatingFunction`, which is defined only for real inputs.

Example:

```
Interpolation[Range[5]^2][1 + I]
```

This returns

[image]

Note that `InterpolatingFunction` does not evaluate to a number, which resembles what appears in the OP's image.

This indicates that the most likely source of the problem is a simple mistake in the definition of `ftbI[]`.

Comment: I see. Is there any sneaky reason you know of that could cause this? I can't figure out how my function is evaluating at a complex point. The function looks approximately like  ```ftbI[x] =...+ Interpolation[x]+...```. I am not using complex numbers at all, and x is a real number that I determine. I can provide more details if interested but I am not sure how useful it would be

Comment: @PhysicsPerson I don't recall seeing it come up before.  So it's either in your code or in a latent definition. (A variable's definition will persist until the kernel is `Quit[]` or the definition is `Clear[]`-ed. If that's the problem, quitting and restarting the kernel would fix it, unless the definition is in your `init.m` file.)